# Hayagriva slokam needed

Tags: vishnu, mantras, vaishnavism, shloka

> **Azhagiya sarasa sanja slokas**

In [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzqR2BUt1O8) telling the name of this slokam at 10:55 min to 11:06 min. This slokas will be help for our **speech**. I need this slokas for improving **speech**

Answer (score 2):

here is hayagreeva mantra's image this may help you :

[image: hayagreeva mantra]